# The preterite with imaginary situations in the future: "if tomorrow it was proven"

Tags: past-tense

Is below sentence is correct?

> If tomorrow it was proven beyond a shadow of a doubt that God does not and never did exist, would you want to remain a part of your religion.

This is because word **Tomorrow** indicates future and **Was** indicate past. 
I think **was** should be replace by **Is** to get correct meaning of sentence.

I know that we use Verb+ed to say imaginary situation which is not true currently. but can we use verb+ed to describe imaginary situation for future.

Also I have learn that we can use Simple present tense to describe future.

Comment: Change "was" to "were" and change the ending period to a question mark. It will then sound grammatically correct to me (U.S. English).

Answer (score 1):

This is called a Subjunctive, which is a verb form that expresses something imagined. The subjunctive is mainly used when talking about things that are not certain to happen. 
[Source: EnglishClub.com](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/subjunctive.htm)

These words are used differently in sentences, so it’s important to know when to use were vs. was.

**Was** should be used in the first and third person singular past, for statements of fact.

**Were** should be used in the second person singular and plural and first and third person plural, for the subjunctive mood to indicate hypothetical statements. In this case, the word **if** indicates the subjective mood. [Source: WritingExplained.org](https://writingexplained.org/was-vs-were-difference)

So, whilst "were" is grammatically correct here, "was" is often substituted in informal settings.